# Cron Jobs in cPanel - run once a day at 9 am

Tags: linux, cron, cpanel, jobs

I am trying to setup my cron jobs to run only once a day at 9 am.

This is what I am using now:

```
  Minute    Hour    Day Month   Weekday 
  0         0,09    *     *        *
```

The problem is that it runs 2 times a day:
- at midnight 00:00
- and at 09:00

How can I make it to run only at 09:00 (once a day)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
0 9 * * * /path/to/your/cron/scrip >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Your cron job will be run at: (5 times displayed)

```
2014-10-14 09:00:00 UTC
2014-10-15 09:00:00 UTC
2014-10-16 09:00:00 UTC
2014-10-17 09:00:00 UTC
2014-10-18 09:00:00 UTC
```

refer [Cronjob Generator](http://www.crontab-generator.org/)